# htaccess rewrite rule: Replace domain, keep the rest

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a simple rewrite rule that does the following:

Example:

```
http://old.com -------> http://new.com

http://old.com/sub1 -------> http://new.com/sub1

http://old.com/sub1/sub2 -------> http://new.com/sub1/sub2
```

etc.

So it just needs to replace the domain name, everything else shouldn't be changed.

I tried this one, but it doesn't really work on my WordPress. What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It should work. Make sure this is 1st rule in your WP .htaccess.

Comment: It works after I changed the order!!! Thank you :)))

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you.